# nan on loss function tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I try to build a model that will identify by data and try to see the LOSS function
loss =tf.reduce_mean(-(y_ * tf.log(y)+(1- y_)* tf.log (1-y)))
But as of now I only get NAN on the prediction and printing NAN in the LOSS function

```
np_labels = np.array(labels)
np_labels = np_labels.reshape([np_labels.shape[0], 1])
features = 910
hidden_layer_nodes = 100
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, features])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([features,hidden_layer_nodes], stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[hidden_layer_nodes]))
z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),b1)
a1 = tf.nn.relu(z1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_nodes,1], stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(0.)
z2 = tf.matmul(a1,W2) + b2
y = 1 / (1.0 + tf.exp(-z2))

loss =tf.reduce_mean(-(y_ * tf.log(y)+(1- y_)* tf.log (1-y)))

update = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(0,50):
        sess.run(update, feed_dict = {x:fvecs, y_:np_labels})
        print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: fvecs, y_: np_labels}))

      #  sess.run(update, feed_dict = {x:data_x, y_:data_y})
     #   print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: data_x, y_: data_y}))

print('prediction: ', y.eval(session=sess, feed_dict =  {x:[[493.9, 702.6, .....
```

i want to print the loss

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a TensorFlow-Issue. This results from the very bad idea of implementing the loss-function yourself.

```
import tensorflow as tf

z2 = tf.random_normal([8, 10]) * 20
y_ = tf.random_uniform([8, 1], minval=0, maxval=10, dtype=tf.float32)

y = 1 / (1.0 + tf.exp(-z2))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(-(y_ * tf.log(y)+(1- y_)* tf.log (1-y)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(loss)  # will always fail with high prob
```

Will give `Inf` just because of missing the log-sum-exp trick which then causes your implementation to fail due to numerical instabilities (a folklore example which produces overflows). Just run this code several times and you get either `NaN` or `Inf`.

Solution would be:

1. replace `y = tf.sigmoid(-z2)` by `y = tf.identity(z2)` to just get the untransformed logits
2. replace `loss = ..` by `loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(...)` to use the numerical stable way

See the docs of [`sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) which explicitly describes this issue.